# cannot read properties of undefined (reading, 'getTextInputValue')

Tags: javascript, node.js

I make a djs modal and I make this values

```
const msg = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('Message');
const id = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('UserId');
```

When I try to get the value this err shows

> `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading, 'getTextInputValue')`

I try to connect the interactions and give another value to (msg,id) but id dosent work

Comment: What makes you think that `interaction.fields` should have a value other than `undefined`? Please read [ask]. Provide a [mcve]. Go through the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).